# How do I include a local SQL Server instance in a ClickOnce application?

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, clickonce

I am building an application that will require the end user to have an local SQL Server instance running on their computer. I have created the database at my end have populated the required base data.

I would like to be able to deploy this application as a ClickOnce from a website.

How do I ensure that my local SQL Server database is included and installed at the client's end?

Comment: If `SQL Express` is not a requirement then i may suggest `SQLite` which required only a local file an no running services.

Comment: I don't mind SQL Express being a requirement, in fact I think I'd prefer it with the amount of potential data the application could create.

Comment: SQL express nowaday support up to 10 gb while SQLite support +/- 140 tb. When choosing db these days, it is more or less a choice of features and platform support. They all offer great db size limit.

Comment: We're off topic. It's running on an SQL instance but how do I get it to install a copy with the end user using ClickOnce?

Comment: I was simply suggesting an easier alternative. Since you absolutely need to use SQL express you need to know that click once does not have any bootstrap for it. You will have to create your own bootstrap. It is doable as I've done it in the past. Also note that since it will be packed within the package and the update is triggered each time the client open the app so when there is a change it will download the whole setup each time and for me it was around 300 mb just SQLExpress. Also you will have to code some contraption as sometimes the instance is being overwriten.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe SQLite is the better way to go then. Presumably the same again, when updating it would overwrite the users created data?

Comment: SQLite is just an option that came to my head. I just mentioned it as it's a file based database. You have many other options too. As a file database system you control your app and can code to check if the db file is located on the computer or not and if it's not you can download from your server an empty database which can be few kilobytes. That become very easy to handle as it's all code side. You can also manually code to install an sql express instance but this require elevated privilege and much more coding than `if(File.Exist(""))`